# beamer, media9 - play multiple videos at once

Tags: beamer, media9

I need to play two videos at once on a slide - it is pretty straightforward to show a single video, however, if I want to show two videos on a single slide simultaneously, it doesn't work - only one video is running.

```
\frame
{
  \frametitle{Motivation}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
       Video1
       \movie[label=show1, height=4cm, width=5cm,poster,autostart]{}{results1.avi}
    \column{.5\textwidth}
      Video2
      \movie[label=show2, height=4cm, width=5cm,poster,autostart]{}{results2.avi}
  \end{columns}
}
```

Any suggestions?
thx...

---

alright, I have media9, however, I'm not able to play any video

```
\includemedia[
  addresource=results.avi,
  width=5cm, height=4cm,
  flashvars={
    source=results.avi
   &autoPlay=true
  }
]{\fbox{Play}}{VPlayer.swf}
```

results.avi is in the same folder as slides.tex, slides.pdf

what's wrong?

is there any simple example? I've already read the package documentation, however there are so many options, that I really don't need... Which player should I use?

---

alright, it seems that .flv does the job, however I have few more questions?

1. How can I play it in a loop (add &loop=true below autoPlay doesn't work)?
2. How can I show some menubar (play/pause, ...) - it isn't necessary to add the buttons into the pdf, show play/pause, etc. on hover is enough (e.g. similar behavior as flash player, etc.)

Comment: Which PDF viewer on which platform do you use?

Comment: Adobe Reader, MacOS

Comment: Then use package `media9` instead of beamer's `multimedia`. The latter implements the oldest media inclusion method for PDF, allowing for only one video playing at a time, the former the most recent inclusion method (AR-9/X), allowing for almost everything.

Comment: @morph Which PDF viewer do you use?

Comment: Adobe Reader - I think that this one is the best

Comment: You should get the most recent version of `media9`. There were problems with `loop` in older ones. `VPlayer` is chromeless (no controls). However, pause video by clicking on it and keep button pressed (move mouse out to keep the video paused), release button for continue playing. It's the video player component that provides controls, not FlashPlayer. Use another player with controls such as StrobeMediaPlayback shipping with media9.

Comment: I've just installed media9 from mactex distribution, so it should be up-to-date... I've tried to use StrobeMediaPlayback, however there appeared message "We are unable to connect the content you've requested. We apologize for the inconvenience" and "TypeError - Error #1009"... why is it so much complicated :(

Comment: `v. 0.7 (2012/05/02)` (look into ChangeLog file or media9.sty)?

Comment: In StrobeMediaPlayback the video source is set through flashvar `src=...`

Comment: yes, I have v0.7

Comment: ok, src works, however loop still doesn't work, the menubar should be hidden as default and progress bar (navigation in video) doesn't work... If I click play, there appeared "buffering..."

Comment: seems the SWF player components are not up-to-date in your media9 installation. With TeXLive-2011 everything works as advertised. MD5 sums: VPlayer.swf 238f65ef517e2f8f58d423836599fd2a; StrobeMediaPlayback.swf 398096de426cdea88e8f76aee3c6f660

Comment: where can I find MD5 sums? sorry for so many silly questions, I'm really not a skilled latex user...

Comment: Download [VPlayer.swf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/players/VPlayer.swf) and [Strobe](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/players/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf) from CTAN into the working directory. Configure Strobe controls through flashvars, see media9 docs.

Comment: hmm, I put these files into the directory with slides.pdf, *.mp4, ... and... nothing... I have texlive2011

Comment: Here is a working [example](ftp://ftp.fz-rossendorf.de/private/grahn/random.zip).

Comment: page cannot be found...

Comment: Try this [link](ftp://ftp.hzdr.de/pub/incoming/grahn/random.zip)

Comment: strange... with yours video, it's ok, however my in flv doesn't work...
the video was created by
    ffmpeg -i seq1_prob.mpg -sameq seq1_prob.flv

Comment: Did you recompile the example file to see if it still works correctly? I had no problems with an flv, recoded from an mpg.

Comment: yes I did - the video works, however loop doesn't work with my flv, it is ok just with yours mp4

Comment: This discussion seems to be moving away from the question and more into the specifics of one case. Perhaps continue it on the [chat system](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: The problem was obviously in videos... now it works! Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you need your video files in MP4 format with H.264 compression. See section 1 of the `media9` documentation on how to recode existing video files / how to recreate them from bitmaps. AVI format is not supported.

To start two or more videos at once, a media button can be inserted that controls them all. Looping the videos is enabled by adding `loop=true` to the Flash variables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\includemedia[
  label=vidA,
  addresource=results1.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  width=5cm, height=4cm,
  flashvars={
     source=results1.mp4
    &loop=true
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\includemedia[
  label=vidB,
  addresource=results2.mp4,
  activate=pageopen,
  width=5cm, height=4cm,
  flashvars={
     source=results2.mp4
    &loop=true
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}

\mediabutton[
  mediacommand=vidA:playPause,
  mediacommand=vidB:playPause
]{\fbox{Play/Pause}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok, thank you, but WHY do I need to recode the video to mp4? Why can't I use standard avi, etc.? I thought that media9 should be better package? I don't want to waste time with this... isn't there a better option?

Comment: The new method is better because `VPlayer.swf` (or any other Flash based player you may find on the web) displaying the video is run in the Reader built-in FlashPlayer. No dependency on external plug-ins that must be installed on the host computer and thus very reliable. FlashPlayer is capable of playing only a small number of video formats (FLV,MP4). MP4/H.264 probably the best combination currently  available.

Comment: Make sure ffmpeg is indeed linked to libx264 library. You may also try flv (FlashVideo): `ffmpeg -i orig.avi -sameq new.flv`

Comment: thank you, it works, however I've updated my question