# media9: "l3kernel too old" (support outdated)

Tags: pdftex, compiling, media9

Well, I was trying to follow this answer ["beamer, media9 - play multiple videos at once"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58104/beamer-media9-play-multiple-videos-at-once), in order to play two videos at the time in one frame.

But the problem is that, after installing the packages movie9, l3kernel and l3packages I'm getting the following error:

```
! media9 error: "support outdated"
!
! Support package l3kernel too old.
!
! See the media9 documentation for further information.
```

I tried to update those packages (`l3kernel` and `l3packages`) but the error is still the same. I don't know if it will help to the understanding of the problem, but I'm using the following code:

```
\begin{frame}
%(...)
\includemedia[
    addresource=cosafea25.flv,
    activate=pageopen,
    width=500,
    height=500,
    flashvars={source=cosafea25.flv &autoPlay=true &loop=true}]{\fbox{Play}}{VPlayer.swf}
%(...)  
\end{frame}
```

I'm compiling in pdflatex with MikTeX in Windows 7.

Edited **8/Sep/13 1:24PM (GMT:-3)**

The *.log file for the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2013.6.23)  8 SEP 2013 13:19
entering extended mode
**test.tex
(C:\Users\AlfonsoS\Desktop\test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3names.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3bootstrap.sty"
Package: l3bootstrap 2013/01/08 v4420 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
)
Package: l3names 2012/12/07 v4346 L3 Namespace for primitives
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count87
)
Package: expl3 2013/03/14 v4469 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3basics.sty"
Package: l3basics 2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Basic definitions
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3expan.sty"
Package: l3expan 2013/02/03 v4458 L3 Argument expansion
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3tl.sty"
Package: l3tl 2013/01/08 v4415 L3 Token lists
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3seq.sty"
Package: l3seq 2013/01/12 v4434 L3 Sequences and stacks
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3int.sty"
Package: l3int 2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count88
\l_tmpa_int=\count89
\l_tmpb_int=\count90
\g_tmpa_int=\count91
\g_tmpb_int=\count92
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3quark.sty"
Package: l3quark 2012/11/04 v4268 L3 Quarks
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3prg.sty"
Package: l3prg 2013/02/13 v4459 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count93
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3clist.sty"
Package: l3clist 2013/01/08 v4414 L3 Comma separated lists
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3token.sty"
Package: l3token 2013/01/10 v4428 L3 Experimental token manipulation
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3prop.sty"
Package: l3prop 2013/01/09 v4423 L3 Property lists
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3msg.sty"
Package: l3msg 2013/01/08 v4412 L3 Messages
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3file.sty"
Package: l3file 2013/01/14 v4446 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count94
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count95
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count96
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count97
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count98
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3skip.sty"
Package: l3skip 2013/01/13 v4444 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3keys.sty"
Package: l3keys 2013/02/24 v4461 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
\g__keyval_level_int=\count99
\l_keys_choice_int=\count100
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3fp.sty"
Package: l3fp 2013/01/19 v4449 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count101
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count109
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3box.sty"
Package: l3box 2013/01/08 v4411 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3coffins.sty"
Package: l3coffins 2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen109
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen110
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen111
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen112
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen113
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen114
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen115
\c_empty_coffin=\box32
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box34
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box36
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen116
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen118
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3color.sty"
Package: l3color 2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3luatex.sty"
Package: l3luatex 2012/08/03 v4049 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
\g__cctab_allocate_int=\count110
\g__cctab_stack_int=\count111
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3candidates.sty"
Package: l3candidates 2013/03/14 v4468 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen123
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen126
\l__box_internal_box=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
))
Package: xparse 2013/03/12 v4467 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count112
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count113
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count114
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count115
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count116
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\media9\media9.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3experimental\l3str\l3regex.sty"
Package: l3regex 2013/07/24 v4576 L3 Experimental regular expressions

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3experimental\l3str\l3tl-build.sty"
Package: l3tl-build 2011/12/08 v3039 L3 Experimental token list construction
\l__tl_build_start_index_int=\count117
\l__tl_build_index_int=\count118
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3experimental\l3str\l3tl-analysis.sty"
Package: l3tl-analysis 2011/12/08 v3039 L3 Experimental token lists analysis
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3experimental\l3str\l3str.sty"
Package: l3str 2013/07/24 v4576 L3 Experimental strings
)
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count119
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count120
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count121
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count122
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3experimental\l3str\l3flag.sty"
Package: l3flag 2011/12/08 v3039 L3 Experimental flags
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3experimental\l3str\l3str-convert.sty"
Package: l3str-convert 2013/01/08 v4339 L3 Experimental string encoding convers
ions
\l__str_internal_int=\count123
\c__str_replacement_char_int=\count124
)
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count125
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count126
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count127
\l__regex_balance_int=\count128
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count129
\l__regex_mode_int=\count130
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count131
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count132
\c__regex_catcode_D_int=\count133
\c__regex_catcode_S_int=\count134
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count135
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count136
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count137
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count138
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count139
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count140
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count141
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count142
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count143
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count144
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count145
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count146
\l__regex_current_pos_int=\count147
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count148
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count149
\l__regex_current_char_int=\count150
\l__regex_current_catcode_int=\count151
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count152
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count153
\l__regex_current_state_int=\count154
\l__regex_step_int=\count155
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count156
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count157
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count158
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count159
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count160
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count161
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\l3keys2e\l3keys2e.sty"
Package: l3keys2e 2013/03/12 v4467 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\atbegshi.sty"
Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
))
Package: media9 2013/08/26 v0.31 acrobat-9/X compatible media


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! media9 error: "support outdated"
! 
! Support package l3kernel too old.
! 
! See the media9 documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.73 }

|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| Please install an up to date version of l3kernel.
| Loading media9 will abort!
|...............................................

) (C:\Users\AlfonsoS\Desktop\test.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
\Gread@gobject=\count162

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count163
\scratchdimen=\dimen134
\scratchbox=\box41
\nofMPsegments=\count164
\nofMParguments=\count165
\everyMPshowfont=\toks14
\MPscratchCnt=\count166
\MPscratchDim=\dimen135
\MPnumerator=\count167
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count168
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks15
)))
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box42
 (C:\Users\AlfonsoS\Desktop\test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7395 strings out of 493921
 139355 string characters out of 3147273
 170582 words of memory out of 3000000
 10639 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 42i,1n,30p,244b,282s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Usually with MiKTeX this comes down to having a multi-user install and failing to update both in 'user' and 'admin' mode. Have you updated for both of these?

Comment: I did, but the error is still the same. Do you think it will be useful to update all the packages?

Comment: Could you try a short file (say `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{xparse}\begin{document}\end{document}`) and post the `.log` here. It would be useful to see what path is being used for the various support files.

Comment: Just did that (posted in question). I also added `\usepackage{media9}`, because it's the package I've issues.

Comment: All 'works for me' with an up-to-date MiKTeX: perhaps try syncing your package database before updating?

Comment: You were right. I synchronized the package database and then updated all the packages and now it works.

Comment: I had the same problem. However, my MikTeX refused to synchro the package database. I uninstalled and reinstalled MikTeX and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently had this issue with media9 and beamer.

When I tried updating the packages didn't work for me.
What worked however, was to remove and reinstall them (l3kernel and l3packages) using miktex package manager.

Comment: Sometimes, with MiKTeX, package update isn't just enough. The package database needs to be (manually) updated too, from time to time (or better just before a package update).

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to Chris's answer above: You may need to run the MikTex Update Manager in both Admin and non-Admin modes. In Windows that means:

Start -> All programs -> MikTex 2.9 -> Maintenance -> Update

and

Start -> All programs -> MikTex 2.9 -> Maintenance (Admin) -> Update (Admin)

Comment: Why not *just* in one mode?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. But in my case, it only seemed to work after I had run in both modes.

Comment: I would imagine running the update as Admin would be superior to and therefore also cover exactly what is achieved when running the update *not* as Admin.

Comment: @Werner I've noticed that Miktex comes installed with a whole set of packages. Install as admin, and those packages need to be updated as admin. Packages you install "on the fly" are installed as user on my comp. So to update those, you need to update as user as well. For me x3kernel was installed as a user.