# How to launch 2 videos simulteneously?

Tags: media9

I want to run synchronously 4 videos on same page. This can be accomplished by launching all videos simultaneously. How to do that? Here is MWE with 2 videos.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\fbox
{\includemedia[
    activate=pageopen,
    width=0.475\textwidth,
    addresource={VertOscAmp(a0_05h0_25dZ1w1_g1rmax20mu0_001)a.mp4},
    flashvars={%
        src=VertOscAmp(a0_05h0_25dZ1w1_g1rmax20mu0_001)a.mp4
        &scaleMode=stretch}
]{}}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}}
    \hfill
\fbox
{\includemedia[
    activate=pageopen,
    width=0.475\textwidth,
    addresource={VertOscAmp(a0_25h1dZ1w1_g1rmax20mu0_001)b.mp4},
    flashvars={%
        src=VertOscAmp(a0_25h1dZ1w1_g1rmax20mu0_001)b.mp4
        &scaleMode=stretch}
]{}}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}}
\\
\caption{caption}
\label{fig:VertOscAmp}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For this, the programming interface of the player must be used. In the case of `StrobeMediaPlayback`, I dont't know how to activate it. But with the other player, `VPlayer.swf` it is easy. Any reason why not using `VPlayer.swf`?

Comment: @AlexG: to the moment, I did not managed to launch `VPlayer` over `VertOscAmp(a0_25h1dZ1w1_g1rmax20mu0_001)b.mp4`. However, after renaming the file to `b.mp4` `VPlayer` works somehow. In any case I would be happy to use `VPlayer`. I am using `StrobeMediaPlayback` by habit. Could you give an example of how to run VPlayer over two videos simultaneously?

Comment: See, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58122 .

Comment: Also note that with `VPlayer` the FlashVar for setting the video source is `source=`, not `src=`. I tried here with a file name like yours and it worked.