# Multiple videos playing as a grid

Tags: beamer, media9, multimedia

Can anyone help me with multiple videos playing simultaneously in beamer ? I need to play 9 different videos as a 3x 3 grid. Any suggestions to adapt this to my problem?  Thank you

[beamer, media9 - play multiple videos at once](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58104/beamer-media9-play-multiple-videos-at-once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example with a 3x3 grid of videos compiles out of the box with current TeXLive-2018. To play videos automatically, a combination of option `activate=pageopen` and Flash variable `autoPlay=true` is required. Tested with AR-DC and FlashPlayer-28.0.0.137.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[passcontext]{media9} %show right-click menu

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{3x3 Video 16:9}
  \setlength\lineskip{0pt}
  \includemedia[
      addresource=example-movie.mp4,
      activate=pageopen,
      flashvars={source=example-movie.mp4&autoPlay=true&loop=false},
      width=\dimexpr\linewidth / 3\relax,
      height=\dimexpr\linewidth * 3/16\relax
  ]{}{VPlayer.swf}%
  \includemedia[
      addresource=example-movie.mp4,
      activate=pageopen,
      flashvars={source=example-movie.mp4&autoPlay=true&loop=false},
      width=\dimexpr\linewidth / 3\relax,
      height=\dimexpr\linewidth * 3/16\relax
  ]{}{VPlayer.swf}%
  \includemedia[
      addresource=example-movie.mp4,
      activate=pageopen,
      flashvars={source=example-movie.mp4&autoPlay=true&loop=false},
      width=\dimexpr\linewidth / 3\relax,
      height=\dimexpr\linewidth * 3/16\relax
  ]{}{VPlayer.swf}\\
  \includemedia[
      addresource=example-movie.mp4,
      activate=pageopen,
      flashvars={source=example-movie.mp4&autoPlay=true&loop=false},
      width=\dimexpr\linewidth / 3\relax,
      height=\dimexpr\linewidth * 3/16\relax
  ]{}{VPlayer.swf}%
  \includemedia[
      addresource=example-movie.mp4,
      activate=pageopen,
      flashvars={source=example-movie.mp4&autoPlay=true&loop=false},
      width=\dimexpr\linewidth / 3\relax,
      height=\dimexpr\linewidth * 3/16\relax
  ]{}{VPlayer.swf}%
  \includemedia[
      addresource=example-movie.mp4,
      activate=pageopen,
      flashvars={source=example-movie.mp4&autoPlay=true&loop=false},
      width=\dimexpr\linewidth / 3\relax,
      height=\dimexpr\linewidth * 3/16\relax
  ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```